# JSF2: bean validation with custom message bundle

Tags: java, bean-validation, message-bundle

I know the issue is discussed in many posts in the forum, however I'm still having problems customizing the messages for the bean validation. Maybe some little things missing in configuration or file location...

When the validation call the message, the web page shows the message ID instead of the message text.

For example I see in the web page {messages.myMessageId}

I have:

**src/com/myapp/view/validationvalidation_en.poperties**

```
webuser_name_notnull = Name is required
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<message-bundle>
        com.myapp.view.validation
</message-bundle>
```

**webuser.java**

```
@NotNull(message = "{webuser_name_notnull}")
private String name;
```

Many thanks for support!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per chapter 4.3.1.1 of the [JSR303 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/edr/jsr303/index.html), the custom JSR303 validation messages file needs to have exactly the name `ValidationMessages.properties` and it needs to be placed in the root of the classpath, in your case thus directly in the `src` folder.

Please note that Bean Validation is not part of JSF. It's part of Java EE of which JSF is also a part. The JSF `<message-bundle>` only definies the location of JSF default validation messages (such as the one which you see on `required="true"`), not the JSR303 Bean Validation messages.

Comment: is there no way to have ValiationMessages.properties not under the root of the classpath? All other message bundles in this legacy application I'm working on are in the /msgs directory @BalusC

Answer (score 3):

You could use a MessageInterpolator. If you use hibernate try this

```
public class ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator extends org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator implements
    MessageInterpolator {

  @Override
  public String interpolate(String message, Context context, Locale locale) {
    // evaluate el expression
    if (message != null && message.startsWith("#{")) {
      FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
      ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
      ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
      ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, message, Object.class);
      Object value = valueExp.getValue(elContext);
      if (value == null) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return value.toString();
      }
    } else {
      return super.interpolate(message, context, locale);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally you need META-INF/validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">
        <message-interpolator>package.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
</validation-config>
```